# Doc.data() doesn't return the documents required, though doc.id returns the id to that document

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-firestore

After mapping an array of ids to ref.doc(id), it returns all records in that collection with that id. But I can't seem to get the documents using doc.data()

```
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('data.json');  
let cleanData = JSON.parse(rawdata);  

let tracksArr = []
let albumsArr = []


cleanData.forEach(v => {
  if (v.Target == "tracks") {
    tracksArr.push(v.TargetID)
  } else if (v.Target == "album") {
    albumsArr.push(v.TargetID)
          }})


var ref = firedb.collection("tracks");
// Map the Firebase promises into an array
const itemPromises = tracksArr.map(id => {
  return ref.doc(id)
})


// Wait for all the async requests mapped into 
// the array to complete
Promise.all(itemPromises)
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
      console.log(doc.data())
    })
    })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

I'm supposed to get the documents on the console. But it says doc.data() is not a function. Can someone help me please?

Comment: I don't think `return ref.doc(id)` returns a promise. Are you looking for `return ref.doc(id).get()`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, ref.doc(id).get() get all the records and they are really large, so it runs out of memory and crashes...Do you know what I'm trying to achieve? Maybe you can help me run the code if I give you the .json file, you can use your own firestore db to test...

Comment: Each call to `ref.doc(id).get()` gets a single document. Right now, you're not calling `get()`, so you're not loading the document, which is why you get the error message when you try to access `doc.data()`.

Comment: There are so many ids, so when I call get, it times out. Do you have any idea how I can solove that? @FrankvanPuffelen